# Threading in Ironpython and WPF XAML

Tags: python, wpf, multithreading, xaml

My question today is easy to ask: How do i run 2 classes at the same time? One would be a ChatBot in python and Second one would be a GUI in an XAML file.

Due to restrictions on my side i cannot change the Bot class enough to use a single thread mixing Bot and GUI, but Multi-threading wasn't an issue when i tried with Python 3.3 and Tkinter:

```
BotChat_thread = threading.Thread(target=BotChat.main)
BotChat_thread.setDaemon(True)
BotChat_thread.start()

BotGUI_thread = threading.Thread(target=mainloop())
BotGUI_thread.setDaemon(True)
BotGUI_thread.start()
```

Nevertheless, I found several limitations in Tkinter and TTK, so I decided to move on and get a different GUI with XAML files. I've been trying to launch just a window and the botchat in different threads and I got unexpected errors such as "mainloop" is not defined. After researching the website for almost 3 hours and several attempts, here I am, stuck :(

Full code:

```
import wpf
import ch #chat library for this specific chat.
import threading
from System.Windows import Application, Window

NICK = "xxxxxx"
password = "xxxxxx"

#BOT
class BotChat(ch.RoomManager):
    def onConnect(self, room):
        room.message("it works")

BotChat = BotChat(NICK, password) #This should turn on the Bot.

#GUI
class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'Login.xaml')

#load both threads
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow()) 

    BotChat_thread = threading.Thread(target=BotChat.main)
    BotChat_thread.setDaemon(True)
    BotChat_thread.start()

    MyWindow_thread = threading.Thread(target=mainloop())
    MyWindow_thread.setDaemon(True)
    MyWindow_thread.start()
```

Also, if multithreading works, I would get the nickname and password to login from the GUI before the Botchat is started. So... i'd appreciate an answer explaining how to Launch the GUI thread before the Bot thread because the Bot one will require of GUI information from Textboxes.

P.S. I'm not native english, apologies if something's wrong.
P.S.2 I'm working now with IronPython 2.7 with support for WPF and Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Where the mainloop is defined? If the error is ` "mainloop" is not define` it is because it is really not defined, and in the code I don't see where.

Comment: There was no need to define mainloop in tkinter, so i never did. Actually, and because of that, i never learned a proper way to use the expression Mainloop. Nevertheless i changed this line `MyWindow_thread = threading.Thread(target=mainloop())` so it looks `MyWindow_thread = threading.Thread(target=Application().Run(MyWindow()))` and although i don't get mainloop errores, the program is just doing nothing and not working.